# segue back and forth between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm implementing a single sign on in my app (user needs to login only once).

but the user can sign out if he wants.

i will explain my problem with a use case flow.

**FLOW:**

1. loginViewController -> user presses login -> i segue to appNavigationController (HomePageViewController is root viewController)
2. HomePageViewController -> user signs out of app -> i segue back to login page
3. user sign's back in.

Now I have a problem.

I get an error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <app.loginViewController: 0x15d559f00> on <app.homeViewController: 0x15d625660> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

And I don't know if this is the problem but the `navigationController` is saving the first `homeViewController` and its not emptying the stack 
I tried to pop the `homeViewController` in `viewDidDisappear`
it didn't work the stack still saves the first `homeViewController`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewControllers needs to be like the following:

> UINavigationController --(rootViewController)--> loginViewController
>   --(Segue)--> HomePageViewController

Or you can do the following:

UITabViewController:

> viewController1 : loginViewController
>
> viewController2 : UINavigationController --(rootViewController)-->
>   HomePageViewController

No, once the user logs in you can navigate to the `viewController2 Tab` and present the `HomePageViewController`

And once the user logs out you can `popToRootViewController` in `viewController2 Tab` & switch to the `viewController1 Tab` to present the `loginViewController`

Comment: can i have a tabViewController with out the tab buttons?

Comment: yeah...you can hide them

Comment: glad to help...check out UITabBarController docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/

Comment: Can i hide the tabs in the storyboard?
it adds the tabs to all my view controllers and messes up the ui

Comment: Yeah, in StoryBoard select your viewController and open the "attributes inspector". You can show and hide bottom bar by changing the dropdown to "none"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one 1 navigationController in your app. I don't think so. 
There should only be one NavigationController, if you want a simple segue back and forth.

Otherwise, if you do have 2 or more NavigationControllers, then you need to programmatically add your new NavigationController to window.

Comment: i only have 1 navigationController.

Comment: login page is a view controller and the rest of the app is in a navigation controller.
in the appDelegate i check if the user is logged in  if he is i set the window to have the navigationController

Comment: If loginviewcontroller has no navigation controller behind, then you cannot "segue back" to it. Your program must start with a navigation controller.